# "The requested URL returned error: 500" when heroku tries to install submodules

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket

I'm trying to push my code repo to heroku, the same way I've done it 100 times in the past, but this time heroku is running into a problem installing a submodule (the same submodule that has been there for years):

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://user:password@bitbucket.org/company/my-submodule.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

I can still clone that repo fine, locally.  It's only heroku that seems to have trouble getting it from bitbucket...

Does anyone know of a way I can get more info on what the 500 error is that bitbucket is, apparently, running into?

Comment: did you ever get any kind of info on this?

Comment: Funny, I have the exact same thing on Bitbucket... was workign 1 hour ago! Looks like an outage on their side - http://status.bitbucket.org/